# Regular expression for phone numbers in c

Tags: c, regex

I have tried this expression for identify a phone number:

```
^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$
```

but this validation is not working with C on Linux.

Comment: Please post your code, and the error. Without that, it's not that easy to help

Comment: C does not natively support regular expressions. What regular expression library are you using?

Comment: Probably BRE or ERE: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/regcomp.3.html

Comment: im using <regex.h> and the error was "warning: unknown escape sequence '\)'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether this works or not. I assume that you are using Extended Regular Expression (`REG_EXTENDED` flag):

```
"^(?\\([0-9]{3}\\))?[-. ]?\\([0-9]{3}\\)[-. ]?\\([0-9]{4}\\)$"
```

ERE is a bit different in the fact that it treats `(`, `)` as literal `(`, `)` and `\(`, `\)` as grouping.

References:

- http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/regcomp.3.html
- http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/regex.7.html

Comment: Of course this will only work for some phone numbers: most of the world is outside North America.

Comment: @Richard: I agree with your point, but I only mirror whatever OP put in his regex.